# Modify javascript forEach result with value from another Array

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to modify the following forEach result with values from another array but I can't get it working.

```
const BbDescriptionDictionary = ['AAA' , 'BBB', 'CCC',] 
const boardBasisOptionsModified = [];  

this.boardBasisOptions.forEach( (value) => {
    boardBasisOptionsModified.push({ 
        "key": value, "value": BbDescriptionDictionary[value] 
    });  
});

this.boardBasisOptions = boardBasisOptionsModified;
```

Comment: what is `boardBasisOptions`?

Comment: btw, your *dictionary* is an array, that means you access it with an index, not a value.

Comment: value is an item in the array "boardBasisOptions"... while you should provide an indexNumber to "BbDescriptionDictionary[value]"...

Comment: You array works with indexes, not named properties. Using `BbDescriptionDictionary[value]` will translate to `BbDescriptionDictionary['AAA']`, while it should be `BbDescriptionDictionary[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to add the `index` parameter in your `forEach` loop:
(I also initialized the `boardBasisOptions` with some values)

See this working snippet:

```js
boardBasisOptions = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];
const BbDescriptionDictionary = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', ]
const boardBasisOptionsModified = [];

this.boardBasisOptions.forEach((value, index) => {
  boardBasisOptionsModified.push({
    "key": value,
    "value": BbDescriptionDictionary[index]
  });
});

this.boardBasisOptions = boardBasisOptionsModified;

console.log("boardBasisOptions:");
console.log(this.boardBasisOptions);
```

Comment: For the sake of example you should log `boardBasisOptionsModified`.

Comment: @Darren I think there is no need, I already log `boardBasisOptions` !

Answer (score 2):

You can give `.forEach` a second parameter, indicating the index of `boardBasisOptions`. Like this:

```
this.boardBasisOptions.forEach( (value, index) => {
    boardBasisOptionsModified.push({ 
        "key": value, "value": BbDescriptionDictionary[index] 
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the value inside your `BbDescriptionDictionay` array using the value and not the index. You have to use the index to access the value of an array.

Just add `index` as a second parameter of your `forEach` function.

```
this.boardBasisOptions.forEach( (value, index) => {
   boardBasisOptionsModified.push({ 
      "key": value, "value": BbDescriptionDictionary[index] 
   });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By taking the index, you could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```
const BbDescriptionDictionary = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC',] 

this.boardBasisOptions = this
    .boardBasisOptions
    .map((key, index) => ({ key, value: BbDescriptionDictionary[index] }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `Array.prototype.map()` to create a new, mutated array rather than worrying about creating temporary arrays, mutating them and then assigning them.

```
const BbDescriptionDictionary = ['AAA' , 'BBB', 'CCC',] 

// Map runs the function on each array item and returns a new array
// with mutated the return value of that function
// Note: ({ ... }) is a shorthand way of returning a value
// (object in this case) without a function body {}
this.boardBasisOptions = this.boardBasisOptions.map((key, index) => ({
  // Shorthand way of assigning a variable to an object using the var
  // name as the key
  key,
  value: BbDescriptionDictionary[index]
})
```

Its is considered bad practice to override properties like this, so I would return the original `boardBasisOptions` to a a new property and use that later on:

```
const BbDescriptionDictionary = ['AAA' , 'BBB', 'CCC',] 

this.boardBasisOptionsWithDescriptions = this.boardBasisOptions.map((key, index) => ({
  key,
  value: BbDescriptionDictionary[index]
})
```

Hope that helps